# Why do objects thrown from a higher height travel farther horizontally?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

The only reason I could think of was that falling from a higher height would mean that it would take more time for the object to travel with the original horizontal component of the1 speed. Any other reasons? For instance, would the magnus effect or bernoulli's principle, or lift be factors?

Comment: The Coriolis effect causes greater horizontal displacement at greater height.

Comment: Adrian Howard - Could you please elaborate?

Comment: At latitudes greater than zero on Earth increased radius from Earth's center, increased height, means increased horizontal speed relative to the surface below.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of throwing an object from some height, and then throwing the **same** object the **same** way from a different height - what "matters" is the amount of time the object in the air. The effects you've mentioned would affect the object in both cases, although these effects will persist for longer when thrown from higher.

There's some philosophy to do with cause and effect here, I suppose, but physically it's just the time it takes to fall.